# How to read the value of a generic type parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have an interface that represents an event and it can have a `type` that I use for discriminated unions:

```
export type Event<T extends string> = {
    /**
     * The type of the event..
     */
    type: T;
};
```

This works really well, but I have to write this boilerplate every time I create a new `Event` type:

```
class TimedOut implements Event<"TimedOut"> {
    public type = "TimedOut" as const;
    constructor(public user: User) {}

    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to somehow read out the generic type parameter's value here so I can create an abstract class that doesn't need `type` as a constructor parameter?

**Clarification:**

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
abstract class EventBase<T extends string> implements Event<T> {
    public type: T = ValueOf<T> //  extracts the string value from the type parmaeter

}
```

which enables me to do something like:

```
class MyEvent extends EventBase<"MyEvent"> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `Event` should be a class... no? Or rather, a function that returns a class to extend...

Comment: How would making `Event` a `class` solve this problem?

Comment: Classes exist as both runtime values and compile time types: https://tsplay.dev/WKPgKw

Comment: What about how the typescript files for the dom events do it? Like `keyof constant` as event arg type?

Comment: `Is there a way to somehow read out the generic type parameter's value here so I can create an abstract class that doesn't need type as a constructor parameter?` Can you show what that would look like in code?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. In my case I'd like to obtain the value `"TimedOut"` to use as the value for `type`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides writing a custom module for the typescript compiler I would not know a way to turn a type into JS code. All your types (generic, interfaces, whatever) are gone at runtime, but I'm quite sure you still need that property.

Let's turn this around.

`class Timeout` already fulfills the `Event` type, you don't need to explicitly say that you implement it; just implement it.

```
class TimedOut {
    public readonly type = "TimedOut";
}

const event:Event = new Timeout();
```

But currently `Event` would complain that it want's it generic type. Let's make it optional.

```
export type Event<T extends string = string> = {
    /**
     * The type of the event..
     */
    readonly type: T;
};
```

"But I need this type" I hear you say. But do you?

```
function someFunction(event:Event<"TimedOut">){}

someFunction(new Timeout());  // accepts new TimedOut() as Event<"TimedOut"> out of the box
someFunction({ type: "Foo" as const });  // complains that it got type:"Foo" but expexted type:"TimedOut"
```

TS can differentiate between different Event types. And If you ever need to extract the type of type:

```
type GetEventType<T> = T extends Event<infer U> ? U : never;

type EventType = GetEventType<typeof t>;
```

[And all together now](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiA3YA7GAeAFTlBhwBMBnOCmKAS2wHM4Bea2hxgPlbgG8AUHGFwA9ACpxQkXHFwCAC1RIUcCADMES4llwA6PdJHjRRuFGABDMhGwAbRAmTAAXPIDcAgL6eBAYztLCioCOgBbYDIAeQBXeEEZMBiAIzs6P3MrG3tHFVQ2ACJQiOi4gs8vAQEMSygEXmxgAHd5cMjYmAAKAEpfdRjsPxg6W2oICIAxAaGR7E7gXRgXTBx8IrbSmAKubr5KgQpx4CnB4dtOxpbi9rie3uFRUThLPz9gMBgqS9aSjp7nqgrXB4da-Mo8CBxNSaGDaZIQEAHI4nGbnPhOFBuAoTCAQAoAuB+Ww0OBee5iJ5EsJgQIMKiwyzwOjwRgQeB5FzY3H45JQ0AoECkMgY1ygm5bKp5OAAcWAMCBMAIzkIPDYRBI5EBizwDHUwDqAFUeAB+OAGuBuRpYKC+KU4iC8WXyxZKlB4PIaBBcTxAA)

Comment: My main problem is that I want to avoid having to write `someFunc<EventType>("EventType")` repeatedly, and this doesn't solve it. Maybe there is no solution after all.

Comment: @AdamArold what about writing `function someFunc<T extends string>(type:T){...}` and calling it like `someFunc("EventType")`. You can't extract the string from the type, but you can determine the type from the string/passed argument.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that I want to listen to events, but they don't necessarily have a `class`, so I can't use `EventClass.name` or something like that, that's why I have the `type` field that I use for a tagged union. Even if I only used classes, then I'm stuck having to enforce that all `Event`s are classes.

Comment: @AdamArold you don't need classes; I'm using less and less classes. You started with classes and inheritance. All you need is any object with a type property that's a string. You can determine the Event type from that property. That's what  `type GetEventType<T>` in my example is for.

Comment: You don't get the point. I don't have an object when I'm creating event listeners. I only have the **type** of the future `Event` that i'm using in a tagged union.